# Do I need to run my Azure function as an async method?

Tags: c#, azure, async-await, azure-functions, .net-7.0

**QUESTIONS** - Why does my Azure function project (isolated process) not contain a namespace, class name or main method in the program.cs file? How come the Azure tools didn't generate this when I created the function project, but still runs? So do I need it?

Also the [Microsoft examples](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/tree/main/samples) (bottom example) all use async methods, should I make my program.cs file async, I thought with Azure functions that would defeat the purpose because each function gets run in its own process?

I created a net7.0 azure function project and noticed that my program.cs file has code like this below with no namespace, program class or main method:

```js
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .Build();
host.Run();
```

And looking at [examples](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/tree/main/samples) that Microsoft has on Github they all have namespaces,  program classes and main methods like below.

```js
namespace Function
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            string sqlConnectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SqlConnectionString");
            var host = new HostBuilder()
                .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
                .ConfigureServices(s => {
                    s.AddDbContext<BloggingContext>(
                        options => options.UseSqlServer(sqlConnectionString)
                    );
                })
                .Build();

            await host.RunAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _"Why does my Azure function project not contain a namespace, class name or main method in the program.cs file?"_ - It does. You just don't see it.

Comment: _"because each function gets run in its own process?"_ - only if you are using the "isolated process" version. In-Process Functions are still a thing, too though.

Comment: Because https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/top-level-statements

Comment: @Fildor - Hi Fildor, I had to create a new "isolated process" function app because I upgraded all my projects to net7.0 and my current in-process function app only supports net6.0 according to MS. And I'm injecting multiple other projects from my solution into my functions, so my function app that references other dll's using net 7.0 wouldn't work with an in-process function app only supporting up to net6

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial answer, hopefully it helps.

You are talking about 'top level statements' which were introduced in .NET 6. In a top level statement entrypoint, the namespace and main method are implicit, and it'll be generated as async if you use await anywhere within it.

Most of the examples from Microsoft were either written before this introduction, or had these elements added for clarity.

I don't know anyone that uses true top level statements in production (unless it's the `IHostBuilder` for web/service/di concerns), I've used them to extract the main method but included a bodyless namespace declaration at the top of the file to clarify that.

```
namespace Function;
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .Build();
await host.RunAsync();
```

Is functionally identical to:

```
namespace Function
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = new HostBuilder()
                .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
                .Build();
            await host.RunAsync(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Andy "I don't know anyone that uses true top level statements in production" so you're saying in production I shouldn't or don't need to use a namespace, class and main method because it's implied like the generated code?

Comment: And what about running it asynchronously? Is async needed in a Azure function?

Comment: Quite the opposite, you should provide a namespace on all files at least. The Main() entrypoint is entirely optional, but the only time I've seen it implied is in cases of a host builder, where there is (effectively) just 2 lines of code - build and run (or runAsync)

Comment: I can't answer if Async is needed in an azure function, but could it hurt to include it? Azure functions are still entire programs, and can be single or multi threaded, so could take advantage of async's potential to multithread. I wouldn't explicitly create threads though.